# How do I read the image currently on the framebuffer in Qt/C?

Tags: c++, c, qt, framebuffer

Is there any way I can read the content of the framebuffer in Qt or anyway in C? I read it is possible to write the content of /dev/fb0 to a file and then load it. But is it possible to avoid saving it to memory and simply copy to a new memory location to use in Qt?
Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you're talking about accessing some kind of low level screenshot for Qt embedded with the *linux* concept of a "framebuffer", and **not** talking about Qt's actual framebuffer *class* for OpenGL...which simply has a `toImage()` method...? http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qglframebufferobject.html#toImage

Comment: I've never seen that class before... seems interesting :-) anyway I would like to take a "low level screenshot", regardless of what was drawing to the framebuffer. I've seen that some interesting structures are in the framebuffer header, but I can't find information about those anywhere.

Comment: If you want that low level, you may want to look at the fbgrab source which seems to be here: http://hem.bredband.net/gmogmo/fbgrab/.

Comment: That might in fact be the best solution to this problem. I didn't go through cause I already solved reading the answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary Qt distribution is not likely to have special support for reading a framebuffer on Linux.  It layers on top of X11 and is trying to provide cross-platform capability (as things like `/dev/fb0` won't have meaning on Windows, for instance).  So you would use higher level abstractions, such as the [QPixmap::grabWindow()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#grabWindow) that @BerkDemirkir points out...probably a lot of hops through layers before the framebuffer.

*(Note: If you are writing an ordinary cross platform Qt app intended to run in a windowed environment, that's certainly the route you want to go for a simple screen capture task!!)*

On the other hand, [Qt/Embedded](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/embeddedlinux-support.html) is designed for Linux and to work with the QWS instead of X11.  The mindset is that there's no windowing system and your app owns the whole screen.  It writes directly to the framebuffer through a `QScreen` object, which has a `base()` method that can actually give you a pointer to the underlying memory:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qscreen.html#base

Those are probably the only "Qt" ways to do these kinds of things.  If you want an API instead of going through to `/dev/fb0` directly you might investigate something like EZFB.  (I didn't dig deep enough to know if it's useful or not, just found it with a query something like "linux framebuffer API")

http://freshmeat.net/projects/ezfb/

Comment: Just to clarify, my problem was simply to get a shot of the framebuffer. Any way was OK for me, both using Qt or simple C/C++. The solution I adopted is using the QApplication::desktopWidget() method and the suggested QPixmap::grabWindow(). I don't know exactly how these classes work, but it seems to be doing what I need. This is quite unexpected as I'm writing to the screen using both OpenGL/EGL and QWS with a custom QScreen implementation I made. The same method is working both under Qt/Embedded and QT/X11. May be interesting to know how to do this using fb directly anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Speaking from intuition here, I could be wrong, but: if you go through `grabWindow()` you can't say for certain you are grabbing the framebuffer device being shown to the user.  It's probably up to the X server to decide what to give you, translated in terms of its virtualized display.  Most of the time that's just the framebuffer.  But for instance: it may be implementing a virtual screen much larger than the physical display.  Again this is all speculation, my knowledge comes mostly from the olden daze of C-64s or ModeX.  :)

Comment: I'm more interested in what happens in Qt/X11. That is interesting, taking also into consideration that OpenGL/EGL is grabbed as well.

Comment: It would surprise me if the X11 server wasn't able to be aware enough to grab it.  But crazier things have happened...I used to have a DVD decoding card on the PC where you'd plug your video card output into it and then take your video off the new card.  The DVD player app just put up a big purple rectangle and then the card would composite the image of the DVD movie into that rectangle.  If you tried to snapshot the movie you couldn't...just a purple rectangle!  OpenGL/EGL on X11 apparently isn't that bad, thankfully!

Comment: :-) the only problem is that I completely failed my last message... too late in the night maybe :-) I meant I'm interested more in Qt/Embedded. That is why I was quite surprised that OpenGL/EGL was appearing in the shot as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can look [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html) to take a screenshot from any window (even desktop). Example uses [`QScreen::grabWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscreen.html#grabWindow) function to take screenshot.

Comment: First link is dead

Comment: Updated to Qt5 and new qt.io links.